# How to use 'would' in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I'm quite confused with the use of "would". Confusing use of would is below:

You use ***you would*** in negative sentences with
verbs such as 'guess' and 'know' when you want to say that something is not obvious, especially something surprising.

⇒ Chris is so full of artistic temperament you'd never think she was the daughter of a banker.

⇒ Inside, he admits, his emotions may be churning, but you would never guess it.

Source: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would

What I'm confused(not understood) is as follows:

Why 'would' has been used in those examples? I don't know how to use 'would' in this way. Could you please interpret it?

Comment: Didn't you ask the [same question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91883/no1-confusing-use-of-would-for-english-learners) before? Wasn't that closed as _'too broad'_?

Comment: It's the edited question but not same question. I've separted the questions into 3

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is clearly shown in your question if you read it attentively.

> 1.You use *would*, or sometimes would have with a past participle, when you are **expressing your opinion** about something or seeing if people agree with you, especially **when you are uncertain about what you are saying** [vagueness]

*Must* is used mostly to express the deduction or coclusion that something is **certain**

The examples are in your question.

> I **would** imagine she is quite lonely living on her own.(The speaker is uncertain about what he is saying).
>
> She **must** be lonely living on her own.(The speaker thinks she is lonely )

Hope it helps.

Comment: I mistakely posted. Now I've edited the question, i hope you'll your answer too.

Answer (score 2):

[would](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) in this context is used to **refer to a situation that you can imagine happening**: see the **POSSIBILITY** section of the link that I have provided.

So, if you say "you would **never guess**...", it means that you **cannot imagine** somebody being able to guess...

Comment: But why that says "something isn't obevious, especially surprising"

Comment: If you can't imagine something, it is not obvous. If it turns out to be true, it's surprising.